# numpy.unique vs collections.Counter performance question

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to compute the number of occurrences of pairs of values. When running the following code the numpy version (pairs_frequency2) is more than 50% slower than the version relying on collections.Counter (it gets worse when the number of points increases). Could someone please explain the reason why.

Is there a possible numpy rewrite to achieve better performance ?

Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

def pairs_frequency(x, y):
    counts = Counter(zip(x, y))
    res = np.array([[f, a, b] for ((a, b), f) in counts.items()])
    return res[:, 0], res[:, 1], res[:, 2]

def pairs_frequency2(x, y):
    unique, counts = np.unique(np.column_stack((x,y)), axis=0, return_counts=True)
    return counts, unique[:,0], unique[:,1]


x = np.random.randint(low=1, high=11, size=50000)
y = x + np.random.randint(1, 5, size=x.size)

%timeit pairs_frequency(x, y)

%timeit pairs_frequency2(x, y)
```

Comment: I cannot replicate your timings: `%timeit pairs_frequency(x, y) 39.3 ms ± 1.96 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)` vs. `%timeit pairs_frequency2(x, y) 15.6 ms ± 200 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

Comment: `numpy` also still wins at 2 orders of magnitude larger for me too. Though, there may well be a better approach possible.

Comment: I get results similar to Gael's, using Python 3.6.4 and NumPy 1.15.2.

Comment: Interesting. I'm on 3.6.3, numpy 1.13.3. Not that I'm sure it matters in this code but it's compiled with MKL on Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.unique` sorts its argument, so its time complexity is O(n*log(n)).  It looks like the `Counter` class could be O(n).

If the values in your arrays are nonnegative integers that are not too big, this version is pretty fast:

```
def pairs_frequency3(x, y, maxval=15):
    z = maxval*x + y
    counts = np.bincount(z)
    pos = counts.nonzero()[0]
    ux, uy = np.divmod(pos, maxval)
    return counts[pos], ux, uy
```

Set `maxval` to the 1 plus the maximum value in `x` and `y`.  (You could remove the argument, and add code to find the maximum in the function.)

Timing (`x` and `y` were generated as in the question):

```
In [13]: %timeit pairs_frequency(x, y)
13.8 ms ± 77.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [14]: %timeit pairs_frequency2(x, y)
32.9 ms ± 631 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [15]: %timeit pairs_frequency3(x, y)
129 µs ± 1.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Note the change in time units of the third result.

`pairs_frequency3` returns the arrays in the same order as `pairs_frequency2`, so it is easy to verify that they return the same values:

```
In [26]: counts2, x2, y2 = pairs_frequency2(x, y)

In [27]: counts3, x3, y3 = pairs_frequency3(x, y)

In [28]: np.all(counts2 == counts3) and np.all(x2 == x3) and np.all(y2 == y3)
Out[28]: True
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried a similar solution to pairs_frequency3 but had concerns about the size of the array returned by np.bincount which could become significantly large if the values in x and y aren't limited to small numbers : with the multiplication z could become very large.

Comment: Yes, that's why I added the wishy-washy qualifier about the values not being "too big". :)